# Wordpress images missing after import

Tags: wordpress, image, import

We have exported our pages out of our old Wordpress site and are now importing them in our new one, but something really strange is happening. We have an export file where all the images are included, but after the import he is deleting the src / image url. Down here you find an example:

Original in the export xml:

```
<img style="margin: 10px; float: right; border: 2px solid black;" title="terrasverwarming-amber-sfeer" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/Terrasverwarming_TH1800R-sfeer.jpg"}}" alt="" width="200" height="200" />
```

In the blogpost after import:

```
<img style="margin: 10px; float: right; border: 2px solid black;" title="terrasverwarming-amber-sfeer" alt="" width="200" height="200" />
```

As you can see the src="{{media url="wysiwyg/Terrasverwarming_TH1800R-sfeer.jpg"}}" is missing after the import.

Does anyone have experience with this and how we can import them including the images?

---

**Solution:**

We have changed the url's from media_url to a static url and after this it is importing fine.

Comment: Could you tell us more information about mechanism of export/import?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, we have solved it and I put the solution in the question